# Verify a Matrix Proof Given $A = A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

### Problem

Given an arbitrary matrix $ A = A^2 $, prove that $ I - 2A = (I - 2A)^{-1}.$

### Attempt

$$ I - 2A = (I - 2A)^{-1} $$
$$ (I - 2A)(I - 2A) = (I - 2A)(I - 2A)^{-1} $$
$$ (I - 2A)(I - 2A) = I $$
$$ (I - 2A)^2 = I $$

This is where I'm not sure if the distributive property can be applied to the following equation. Assuming it can be,

$$ (I - 2A)^2 = I $$
$$ I^2 - 4A + 4A^2 = I $$
$$ I^2 - 4A + 4A = I $$
$$ I^2 = I $$
$$ I = I $$
$$ [LHS] = [RHS] $$

### Notes

Is it possible to prove this property is satisfied without using the distributive property as I did above? *And what would be an actual example of such a matrix A that satisfies this property?*

### Solution to Proof

*After reviewing and understanding multiple solutions, including that of @JMoravitz, I've come to the following solution.*

Consider $ (I - 2A)^{2} $. We must first show that $ (I - 2A)^{2} = I$.

$$ (I - 2A)^2 = (I - 2A)(I - 2A) $$
$$ (I - 2A)^2 = I^2 - 4A + 4A^2 $$
$$ (I - 2A)^2 = I^2 - 4A + 4A $$
$$ (I - 2A)^2 = I^2 $$
$$ (I - 2A)^2 = I $$

Therefore, $ I - 2A $ is the inverse of $ I - 2A $, by the definition of matrix inversion.

An example of such a matrix that satisfies this property is the $ I_{2 \times 2} $ matrix, which is an [idempotent matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix).

\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Why are the answers here getting downvoted?

Comment: @KeyFlex Oh, that makes sense––solves my latter question.

Comment: And @ConnorHarris good question... Thanks for providing an alternate A matrix! Is there a common property between that matrix and a 2x2 identity matrix?

Comment: What you did seems legit. An example of such matrices is the identity matrix.

Comment: I don't see any problems here.  I have no clue why people are getting downvoted - must be the full moon ;-)

Comment: @ConnorHarris If you consider $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ then $A\ne A^2$.

Comment: @KeyFlex You're right about that. I was rash in not performing a calculation to make sure Connor Harris's matrix satisfied the condition. That being said, there are more [idempotent matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix) that when multiplied by themselves, yield themselves.

Comment: @KeyFlex: consider $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ (I agree my previous suggestion was wrong).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are told that $A=A^2$ and from this we must prove that $(I-2A)=(I-2A)^{-1}$.

Reworded, letting $P$ be the proposition that $A=A^2$ and letting $Q$ be the proposition that $(I-2A)=(I-2A)^{-1}$ we need to prove that $P\implies Q$

In your attempt, you tried to show that $(Q\wedge P)\implies\textbf{True}$.  This is **not** the same thing as proving that $P\implies Q$.  You started with what you want to show.  This is not allowed.

Consider for a counterexample, the claim that if $p$ is a prime number then it is equal to $2$.  That is, $p\text{ is prime}\implies p=2$.  You should know that this is a false implication, for example $3$ being a prime number different than $2$.  In your attempt, it is as though you began your proof by saying "*Let $p=2$ (*and let $p$ be a prime number*).  Then $2=2$, therefore all prime numbers are equal to $2$.*"

Instead, you should begin with your hypotheses and work *towards* your desired outcome.  (*Admittedly it is sometimes useful to work backwards by starting with the desired outcome and performing manipulations, however this is dangerous.  Especially when some of the steps are not biconditional, for example taking square roots or dividing by unknowns which could be zero*).

---

The start of a correct proof.  Suppose that $A=A^2$.  Consider $(I-2A)^2$.  We wish to prove that $(I-2A)^2=I$ which would then imply that $(I-2A)=(I-2A)^{-1}$.

$(I-2A)^2 = (I-2A)(I-2A)=\cdots$

> $=I-4A+4A^2=I-4A+4A=I$

To answer your question about whether or not the distributive property works for matrices, it does!  You have for matrices of appropriate dimension $(A+B)(C+D)=AC+AD+BC+BD$.  Be careful however and remember that most matrices will not commute with eachother, so for example $(A+B)(A+B)=A^2+AB+BA+B^2$ is potentially different than $A^2+2AB+B^2$.  Identity matrices do always commute with everything.

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! It really hits the mark in terms of defining the proper procedure for supplying the proof, as well as for answering the majority of the original question (minus the example part at the end, but that's already been answered in the comments). I added an **Updated Proof** section in my question, and I'd appreciate it if you took a look at it to ensure that it begins with my hypotheses and works towards my desired outcome.

Comment: @Anthony I personally dislike the "two-column" style that you displayed much of your work in, instead preferring to have it all appear in a single line with several equals signs (*though I will stray from this on occasion if it makes it clearer*).  As for the final bit where you "multiply both sides by $(I-2A)$" and you rewrote $I$ as $(I-2A)(I-2A)^{-1}$, this was unnecessary (*Remember that if $A\cdot B=I$ this implies _by definition_ that $B=A^{-1}$*) and further you referred to $(I-2A)^{-1}$ before remarking on the fact that we now have enough information to know $(I-2A)$ is even invertible

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can apply the distributive property with matrices, but be careful with multiplication (you must preserve the order), because it is not commutative, so for example:

$$(A+B)(C+D)=AC+AD+BC+BD$$

An example of a matrix satisfying $A=A^2$ is $ \begin{bmatrix} 2&-2&-4 \\ -1&3&4 \\1&-2&-3 \end{bmatrix}$.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix

Answer (score 2):

Such a linear transformation, $A^2=A$, is called a *projection*.

For example, an orthogonal projection:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$.

You seem to have all the elements of a proof that $I-2A=(I-2A)^{-1}$...